# SEO Object Indexing Not Happening In Community

Tags: community, guest-user, seo

We're running into an issue where no objects are appearing under Settings -> SEO -> Object Access. I've tried all the steps listed here (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_seo_object_access.htm&type=5)

Which are:

- Make sure the guest User profile has at least read access to the object and the appropriate fields
- Create a sharing rule that shares the records with the community guest user
- Publish the community

However, the list never seems to update. Strangely it works in the copy sandbox, but not in our production org. Both are currently on Winter '21. For those who have done this recently, are there any steps I'm missing or overlooking?

Comment: How long has it been since you made a changes on Prod "It can take up to 24 hours for the list of available objects to appear along with the number of indexed records."?

Comment: @ytiq It's been a few days since making the required changes, unfortunately. Also weirdly that help article mentions it could take 24 hours, but in Builder it says "After publishing, it can take several minutes for the list of indexed objects to appear". Wonder which one is correct.